# Aligning a 3x4 matrix pointer to 16

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a function which returns an unaligned 3x4 matrix pointer. I want to be able to align this pointer to 16 and then pass it on to another function. Is there any way to do this?

```
using matrix3x4 = float[ 3 ][ 4 ];

matrix3x4 *UnalignedPointer();
void AlignedPointer( matrix3x4 *aligned );

void Function() {
   matrix3x4 *arr = UnalignedPointer();
   // allign arr
   AlignedPointer( arr );
}
```

Comment: What does align to 16 mean?

Comment: trying to do an equivalent of alignas( 16 ) on the data

Comment: Allocate more space and align start to 16

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: What is stopping you from using `alignas` as you mentioned yourself?

Comment: Because alignas works for types. I dont want a separate type. I want to pass in a matrix3x4 pointer, just aligned. Unless you can enlighten me on how to use it with my code.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not at all easy to "re-align" a type, you probably have to re-allocate the memory, which gets "expensive" (and risks memory leaks, since you also have to have a mechanism for freeing your extra allocated memory, as well as the original memory).

In gcc and clang, you can align a type by adding `__attribute__((aligned(16))`, and MS compilers support `__declspec(align(16))`, which means the compiler will do it's level best to make the type align to 16 bytes in the first place. Given that the minimum size for your type is 3 x 4 x 4 bytes = 48 bytes, which is already aligned to 16, it's unlikely to add MUCH memory to your overall footprint.